# Babel hook that runs after all files are processed?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

In Babel plugins, there's a `post` hook, which runs after processing a single JS file. However, I want to run some code after all JS files are processed. Is this possible?

For now, I just added a new plugin which runs after the first plugin, but it'll be cleaner if they're one plugin.

Comment: What tool are you using to run Babel? Webpack, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that Babel does not provide a hook like this because Babel's core transformation system runs one file at a time. The entire API is:

```
babel.transform("var foo; /* some code */", { filename: "foo.js" });
```

so it has no way to register something that would run after a *group* of files has been processed.

The longer answer is that, if you're using Webpack specifically, you can use Babel in combination with a Webpack plugin to collect metadata from each individual file, and then perform some action with all of that metadata, but that is a Webpack/babel-loader-specific feature. An example of one such Webpack plugin is [`react-intl-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/Ognian/react-intl-webpack-plugin/blob/0915e5449a8df9fb566304be72f83287e51dd7db/index.js#L23), which is paired with [`babel-plugin-react-intl`](https://github.com/yahoo/babel-plugin-react-intl/blob/6d364b01554f80433067202f342d6b516b03daaa/src/index.js#L193).